# why chrome web app shortcuts has no Icon

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, .desktop, webapps

I am creating web app shortcut from chrome to desktop by clicking on more tools > create shortcut.

But it has random name and no icon as clear, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

After clicking "Trust and Launch", I can launch the web app by double clicking the file, but the icon still is not the correct icon.

Here are the contents of the file when viewed in `gedit` text editor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=YouTube
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default --app-id=adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh
Icon=chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh
```

I can see the name of the icon in the `Icon=` field, and I can find that icon in the filesystem, as you can see below:

```
sudo updateddb
sudo locate chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh
/home/idea/.gnome/apps/chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.desktop
/home/idea/.local/share/applications/chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.desktop
/home/idea/.local/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.png
/home/idea/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.png
/home/idea/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.png
/home/idea/.local/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.png
/home/idea/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.png
```

Comment: What do you get after clicking on "Trust and Launch"?

Comment: @Kulfy works fine, I just wanna get regular Icon and name

Comment: @Kulfy didn't help

Comment: Let's find out if there's an icon with this name and where is it. Run `sudo locate chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh`

Comment: @Kulfy yes there is many of them, I've edited the question with the command result

Comment: It looks .png is missing in icon's entry. Edit the file and add .png, so that it looks like `Icon=chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.png`.

Comment: @suhayb what is your Ubuntu Version? based on your details in question.. you are using the APT version of chroium web browser. once you click on "Trust and Launch" the icon and name must change. did you try it?

Comment: @pratap yes I've tried trusting it, nothing changes after app opned nor closed, ubuntu 18.10, same thing for chrome

Comment: did the name on destop changed to `YouTube` when it opened or aftet closed.

Comment: @PRATAP No, even the the icon stays broken

Comment: but its opening as normal rite?

Comment: @PRATAP yes it opens regularly

Comment: can you just copy paste the content in a new text file and name it as YouTube.desktop https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUZOk.gif

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because your desktop icon is not able to find appropriate icon location.

Just replace your line in the file

> Icon=chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default

with the location of icon, like:

> Icon=/home/idea/.local/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/chrome-adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh-Default.png

Save the file, and Youtube icon as well as the name should come up once you double click on it and try launching it.

Signing out and signing in can help, in case the icon fails to load after launching it as well.

PS: In case the icon isn't displayed properly, please try other folders with dimension 48x48 or 128x128 instead of 32x32 in the above path as you can see in the result of your locate command.

Comment: That's an intended mechanism. If you only declare the icon name, the system will look for the file in the appropriate folder, depending on the size that is needed.

Comment: ... If absolute path isn't defined, it automatically looks into hicolor folder which is default icon pack of Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, that's where Chrome (and Brave) store the icons for their web apps. It's so annoying that in alacarte it's easy to change the icon to a new icon but there seems to be no way to figure out what is the full pathname to the CURRENT icon!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was `xdg-icon-resource` issue. I reproduced the issue by starting google-chrome-stable and then creating a shortcut and received this message:

```
/usr/bin/xdg-icon-resource: line 1076: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
```

The issue was fixed when I replaced `xdg-icon-resource` (it's a bash script) file content with this one https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/xdg-utils/+/57bfa1ab873467031b744e5239304efa15fbe54f/scripts/xdg-icon-resource

PS: you will need to recreate the shortcuts!